# What are the types of these function arguments?

Tags: c++

What is the meaning of `const T u[DESCRIPTOR::d]` and `const T pi[util::TensorVal<DESCRIPTOR >::n]` in the parameters for this function? Are `u` and `pi` arrays whilst `DESCRIPTOR::d` and `util::TensorVal<DESCRIPTOR >::n` indices of the array? Then why in the function can they call `u` and `pi` directly?

```
void Dynamics<T,DESCRIPTOR>::iniRegularized(
  Cell<T,DESCRIPTOR>&cell,
  T rho,
  const T u[DESCRIPTOR::d],
  const T pi[util::TensorVal<DESCRIPTOR >::n])
{
  T uSqr = util::normSqr<T,DESCRIPTOR::d>(u);
  for (int iPop=0; iPop<DESCRIPTOR::q; ++iPop) {
    cell[iPop] = computeEquilibrium(iPop, rho, u, uSqr) + firstOrderLbHelpers<T,DESCRIPTOR>::fromPiToFneq(iPop, pi);
  }
}
```

Comment: T and DESCRIPTOR are templates ```const T u[DESCRIPTOR::d]``` declare an array of type T which is auto deduced from class Dynamics of size d which is located under the template DESCRIPTOR.

Comment: `DESCRIPTOR::d` should be a `constexpr std::size_t` to represent the size of the array. But as c-arrays cannot be passed by value, parameter `const T u[DESCRIPTOR::d]` is equivalent to `const T u[]` (or `const T* u`).

Comment: To the close voters: What is unclear about OPs misunderstanding? They have shown context of the code and stated the particular syntax they are confused by, including their initial guess.

Comment: I suspect that the two array arguments should be `const T (&u)[DESCRIPTOR::d]` and `const T (&pi)[util::TensorVal<DESCRIPTOR>::n]` and then `uSqr` could _probably_ be initialized without explicitly specifying the template parameters. `T uSqr = util::normSqr(u);`

Comment: @TedLyngmo at most with similar modification to the arguments to `util::normSqr`

Comment: @Caleth Yeah, you are correct. It'd be interesting to see how all the involved types and functions are declared.

Answer (score 0):

I believe they are declaration of a fixed size array of type `T` where `d` and `n` are defined in the `class` `DESCRIPTOR` and `util::TensorVal<DESCRIPTOR>` respectively.

Furthermore, I would expect the type `T` to have numerical trait so that the array is representing vector (based on the name of the functions that are using `u` and `pi`).

Edit: changed `namespace` -> `class`

Comment: I did not know that :).